# terraform = invalid character ' \r' in string literal

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm using Terraform to deploy resources using Azure ARM.

I'm getting the following error from Terraform

```
 invalid character ' \r' in string literal
```

I couldn't find any characters like this one in the ARM template that I'm using.

Any idea where the error could be?

Comment: `\r` is likely denoting (a fragment of) a new line character.

Comment: Thank you @GrzegorzOledzki, it helped me debug the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it was due to the `\n` that was manually added to the JSON file.

While the Az CLI worked through it, Terraform didn't.

[image]

Once I remove those `\n`s, it worked fine:

```json
"input": {
    "id": "[resourceId(parameters('vnets')[copyIndex('vnetRuleArray')].vnetResourceGroup, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('vnets')[copyIndex('vnetRuleArray')].vnetName, parameters('vnets')[copyIndex('vnetRuleArray')].vnetSubnetName)]", "ignoreMissingVNetServiceEndpoint": "[parameters('vnets')[copyIndex('vnetRuleArray')].ignoreMissingVNetServiceEndpoint]"
}
```

Comment: Preferably, paste the JSON inline, as you did with your second example, rather than pasting a screenshot. I imagine you did that here to show the line numbers? But I think you can still indicate that here, in Markdown, since Stack Overflow doesn't wrap code.